# Logs of a command task in Informatica

Tags: informatica

How to See logs of a command task as except sessions we can't see the logs in [Informatica](https://network.informatica.com/thread/6726). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see a log of a command task you have to create it this way:
*your command*  *>path at your server*
For example:

```
C:\Script\backup.bat >C:\Logs\MyLog.txt
```

Comment: thanx for the help!!!
I have added the below logs information in my script
exec 1> /home/a0c9sx/Encounter_CMS_MAO_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log 2>&1
However in the logs I'm able to see such things
Permission denied
/home/a0c9sx/script.sh[34]: /app/Informatica/infa_shared/infa_shared/ParamFiles/A0C9SX_Encounter_cms_param.prm: cannot create
The workflow wf_s_m_unc_lkp will be started from folder a0c9sx 
unknown environment ENV_CMD
Unable to retrieve value for INF_SERVICE

If I can get some help on that ,it will be useful
Thanx in Advance :)